# DesktopCleanup of ZK is not called in IE 9

Tags: java, internet-explorer, zk

all, I have encountered one interesting question about "DesktopCleanup"

There are two ways to do something after closing the browser:

```
public class MyDesktopCleanup implements DesktopCleanup {
    public void cleanup(Desktop arg0) throws Exception {
     System.out.println("Close browser======");
    }
}
```

then write into zk.xml: 
listener description:MyDesktopCleanup 
listener-class:com.text.MyDesktopCleanup

or, you can do this: ===============

```
@Override
public void doAfterCompose(Component comp) throws Exception {    
    super.doAfterCompose(comp); 

    comp.getDesktop().addListener(new DesktopCleanup() {            
        public void cleanup(Desktop desktop) throws Exception {                                             
            System.out.println("Close browser======");              
        }
    });     
}
```

I have test these two methods in Chrome and firefox, they both operated well and print :"Close browser======". But if I run this in IE 9, something interesting happened: after running the web project and I open IE 9 to access the web page. Before closing IE, I do nothing, then the DesktopCleanup is called and it is right. However, if I do something like upload files on web page, after closing IE, the DesktopCleanup would be not called.

So, how can I resolve this problem ? Thank you very much!

Comment: That should go to the zk bug tracker. http://tracker.zkoss.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa?mode=hide

Comment: Hi, Nabil, thank you for answer. And during opening this URL, I have got "There is no current active search."  Did you mean make me to submit one bug like my quesion?

Comment: Yes, I mean that this is a bug and you should post a bug to the tracker.

Comment: OK, get it. I will do it.